# Connect endpoint VPN client to multiple vnets in azure

Tags: azure, vpn, vnet

I have three vnets that I would like to make accessible to end users. The three vnets can talk to each other via peering. If I setup a VPN gateway, the VPN can only connect to the vnet that the gateway is setup to.
I have the **`allow gateway transit`**, **`use remote gateways`** as well as **`allow forwarded traffic`** enabled. I've also redownloaded the VPN client.
Is there an option I'm missing that will let the VPN clients connect to all three vnets?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Virtual Network Gateway to send on-premises traffic transitively to a peered VNet, the peered VNet IP range for the on-premises VPN device must be set to 'interesting' traffic. Otherwise, your on-premises resources won't be able to communicate with resources in the peered VNet.

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#create-a-peering